# Alinear <a> en HTML

Tags: html

Quiero saber si la manera de alinear texto del enlace  es la siguiente:

```
<a text-align="center" href=<%=rs("IDENTIDICACION")%> download=<%=rs("IDENTIDICACION")%>>TEST</a>
```

Debido a que no se centra la palabra: test

Comment: estas usando sintaxis de css esta seria la forma para html:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar con estos estilos:

```css
a{
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="" >TEST</a>
```

O si los quieres en linea:

```html
<a href="" style="text-align: center; display: inline-block; width: 100%; ">TEST</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

estas usando sintaxis de css esta seria la forma para html:

```
text-align="center"//no
align="center"//si
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregando **CSS** (**text-align** y **margin**) de la siguiente manera:

```
<a style="text-align:center; margin:auto;" href=<%=rs("IDENTIDICACION")%> download=<%=rs("IDENTIDICACION")%>>
     TEST
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba de esta manera:

```
<p style="text-align:center;">
<a href=<%=rs("IDENTIDICACION")%> download=<%=rs("IDENTIDICACION")%>>TEST</a>
</p>
```